# Can I use any mail server with Google Apps Script, or am I limited to using Gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting

Google Apps Script limits users to sending 100 messages a day. If I using my own mail server, can I bypass this limit?

Comment: You can make 20,000 `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` calls a day.  So, if you can trigger an email being sent with an HTTPS GET or POST request, that might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using your own mail server, you don't need GAS. you can just use bash or python scripting and use `sendmail`. Here's a link to the basic syntax: http://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/

Comment: I want to build an app around Google Drive. If I use python, I won't be able to use a Google spreadsheet as a database.

Comment: why not? you can always write externally to a google spreadsheet, easily, from python. I do it all the time. check up python 'gspread'.